# SQLAlchemy data model using 2 databases/servers connections

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have this requirement in a project for which I am struggling to find a solution.

Consider we have a data model that defines a bunch of tables, let's say tables: `A, B, C, D` in MySQL.

We have a SQLAlchemy model defined on top of them through which we are performing different operations(joins, filters, etc.) amongst them.

Now, consider tables `A and B`, have their data loaded from a bunch of CSV files in the MySQL database prior to our script executions and `C and D` are standalone in the database.

Our goal would be to remove these `A and B` tables from MySQL and just use them on the fly as code executes (local sqlite or some in memory database), but without changing the models and queries used through SQLAlchemy (switching to python native code for doing these operations would be too much refactoring).

Is there any way to achieve this? Basically define a SQLAlchemy model across 2 database instances on what is basically 2 different servers?

Do you have any suggestions on this might be solved with little impact to the SQLAlchemy model?

Thanks!